# Could not find Spring Profile when uses JUnit Runner in IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

I'm trying to run a JUnit Test in IntelliJ IDEA, but the Runner could not find the Spring Profile.

this message is displayed in the log:

> --spring.profiles.active=dev

but right after:

> Could not find key 'spring.profiles.active' in any property source

and at the end the profile used is *default*

This is where I'm trying to set the profile in IntelliJ:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem. Everything works when I remove the "--" of the *Environment variables.*

**This:** --spring.profiles.active

**To:** spring.profiles.active

Comment: It's also possible to pass profile as VM argument: java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod application.jar

Answer (score 0):

Under "Build and run" --> "Environment variables:", add:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=[profile name]
```

Ex:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=testing
```